# GWT dev mode not accepting requests forwarded through router

Tags: gwt, firewall

Our application uses the PayPal api, in order to test it PayPal needs to be able to post data to a serlvet on our servers.  This is no problem in production however when running in GWT-Dev mode I cannot seem to get GWT to work through my home router.  GWT is running on port 8888 and I have added the needed firewall rules to get this to work.

Does GWT somehow stop requests from working from outside the local area network?  I tried -bindAddress 192.167.x.x  but it did not work.

Comment: Do you have the access to your company machine? Is Firewall on?

Comment: It is my home machine the Windows Firewall is off and the router is configured to expect a virtual server on my ip address and port.

Comment: I am asking that is firewall on in your company's machine where you are trying to access the servlets? Or do they have implemented Servlet Filtering for some IP address.

Comment: I am trying to allow paypal's servers to access my server running on my workstaion.

Comment: May be this link can be a help http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideTestingRemoteTesting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons the jetty server used in gwt dev mode only binds to localhost.

If you want to bind it to all intefaces use the parameter -bindAddress 0.0.0.0

To make sure the servlets are reachable try to connect from a different host on your network (e.g. with Telnet).